# AutoHotKey - Functions cannot contain functions error

Tags: autohotkey

I'm new to AutoHotKey and I wanted to create a script macro for a flash game but when I run it, it creates an error.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

condChecker := false
state := true

Mine() 
{
    Sleep, rand(10,80)
    Send, {Space}
    while(state = true) 
        {
                PixelGetColor, gemColor, 982, 433
        if(gemColor = B93557) 
        {
            state := true
        {
        else(gemColor = 96885A) 
        {
            state := false
        }
                Sleep, rand(90,120)
        }
}

^-::
loop 10000 
{
    getState()
    if(state = true) 
        {Mine()}
    else
        {Sleep, rand(70,150)}
}
```

When I press Run Script on the ahk file, a menu pops up saying

Error at line 20.

Line Text else(gemColor = 96885A)
Error: Functions cannot contain functions.

The program will now exit.

I don't know where to start with this error and I read up on other forums saying that my formatting was incorrect.

Comment: Did you mean to write `else if (...)`? https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfExpression.htm#ExComplex

Answer (score 1):

A couple of various things:

1. The curly brace after `state := true` should be the other way (<kbd>}</kbd>, not <kbd>{</kbd>)
2. There is no default `rand` function in AHK, you are probably either looking for [Random](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Random.htm), or you have a custom function called `rand` that you is not shown in your question. In any case, I'll write a function `rand(a,b)` that will return an integer value between a and b

```
rand(a, b)
{
    Random, rand, a, b
    return rand
}
```

3. Additionally, there is another function `getState()` that is being invoked inside the `loop 10000`. I'm not sure what it is supposed to do (or if you meant something like [GetKeyState](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm) instead), but I'll assume that you have that covered on your end.
4. As @Pranav Hosangadi mentioned, you likely wanted an `else if` statement instead of just an `else` statement on this line: `else(gemColor = 96885A)`
5. Are you sure you want `SendMode Input`? Although it does have superior speed than standard `Send`, its use is normally limited to typing text in a text box. It seems that you are trying to send a keystroke to a flash game, so you might want to check whether that functioning as you intend it to.
6. When writing a end curly brace (<kbd>}</kbd>) to conclude an `if()` or `else()` clause, you need to put it on its own line. (i.e. change

```
    if(state = true) 
        {Mine()}
    else
        {Sleep, rand(70,150)}
```

to something like

```
    if(state = true) 
        {
            Mine()
        }
    else
        {
            Sleep, rand(70,150)
        }
```

or even (since the `if` and `else` statements here only trigger one line of code each)

```
    if(state = true) 
        Mine()
    else
        Sleep, rand(70,150)
```

---

So, that was a bit long, but here is the final code:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
; ---> Double check this! ---> SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

condChecker := false
state := true

Mine() 
{
    Sleep, rand(10,80)
    Send, {Space}
    while(state = true) 
        {
                PixelGetColor, gemColor, 982, 433
        if(gemColor = B93557) 
        {
            state := true
        }
        else if(gemColor = 96885A) 
        {
            state := false
        }
                Sleep, rand(90,120)
    }
}

rand(a, b)
{
    Random, rand, a, b
    return rand
}

^-::
loop 10000 
{
    ;getState()
    if(state = true) 
        Mine()
    else
        Sleep, rand(70,150)
}
```

lmk if something doesn't work properly, and I'll try to update this response

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. The code runs but it seems like there is an error in my logic that I don't understand. In the game, There is a gemstone that will be above my character. You will know when a rock has a gemstone in it when it has a red gemstone poking out of it. When you press space bar, it will automatically until the gemstone is mined. The mining will continue until the gemstone is mined out or the player pressed space again. You will know the gemstone is done mining when the areas with the red gemstone become brown. The game is a 2D pokemon flash game so the gemstone

Comment: position will always stay in the same place. When I run the current program, it just spam presses the space bar. I don't understand why this occurs even after looking over my code. If I knew how to send screen shots I would but I don't even know how to reply to answers so here I am.